# What upgration need to be done if Apache IoTDB server and jar are in different version?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Do the Apache IoTDB database version and `iotdb-session` version need to be strongly consistent? At present, our IoTDB database is 1.1.0, but the jar of the coding is still Version 1.0.0. Will there be any impact if we don’t upgrade the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, the versions can be compatible downwards.
If you don't use the interface of the new version of Apache IoTDB, and use the session of the old version, then the usage will not be affected.
If there are major bugs and you need to upgrade the older version, you can just download the latest session and use it to recompile the system.
Thanks!